# Aliasing inside constructor - class Point

Tags: java

This my Point class:

```
public class Point
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public Point(Point other)
    {
        _x = other._x;
        _y = other._y;
    }

}
```

Inside Point constructor i need to do something else to avoid aliasing or what i have done is OK ?

Comment: Consider respecting standard Java naming conventions, and not prefixing your variables with `_`. Also, why don't you test it instead of asking us?

Comment: i already test it but it's always good to here other opinions

Comment: FYI, this is called [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4), not aliasing.

Comment: BTW in case i want to return Point do i need to return new Point or just the Point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be fine. Personally, I like to use `this` in constructors for clarity, but it's a matter of style:

```
public Point(Point other)
{
    this._x = other._x;
    this._y = other._y;
}
```

Comment: And inside Set method that set point i need to do something like this ? -->  public void setCityCenter(Point cityCenter)
 {
  _cityCenter = new Point(cityCenter);
 }

Comment: You **can**, but since your implementation of `Point` is immutable, that would be redundant - just save `_cityCenter = cityCenter;`.